# Como faço para saber a hora e a data de um local com PHP?

Tags: php

Pretendo armazenar em uma variável a hora atual de Portugal e em outra variável a data atual de Portugal.

Como poderei fazer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');

$dia = date('Y-m-d'); // 2016-12-24
$hora = date('G:i'); // 16:29
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/VTSFCg)

Nota que na demonstração, a hora não está bem, mas deve ser por causa da plataforma ideone.

Answer (score 1):

Configure o `date_default_timezone_set` para `Europe/Lisbon` e veja funcionando [**aqui no ideone**](http://ideone.com/OJHiUE):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');

$date = time();
$date = date('Y-m-d', $date);
$hour = date('H:i:s', $date);
echo "Data: ".$date."\n";
echo "Hora: ".$hour;
```

Você pode conferir a lista de suporte de Fusos horários [aqui na documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) do PHP.